# Define an injection from $2^{\Bbb N}$ to $\Bbb R$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Define an injection from $2^{\Bbb N}$ to $\Bbb R$

---

Does this proof look fine or contain logical gaps and flaws? Thank you for your help!

---

We define a mapping $F:2^{\Bbb N} \to \Bbb R$ by $$\forall f\in2^{\Bbb N}: F(f)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{f(n)}{3^{n+1}}$$

It's clear that for all $f\in 2^{\Bbb N}$: $$F(f)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{n=k}\dfrac{f(n)}{3^{n+1}}$$ and $$F(f)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{f(n)}{3^{n+1}}\le \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{3^{n+1}} = \dfrac{1}{2}$$

Thus $F(f)$ is the limit of a strictly increasing and bounded above sequence of rational numbers. Hence $F(f)$ exists for all $f\in 2^{\Bbb N}$.

For $f_1,f_2\in 2^{\Bbb N}$ and $f_1\neq f_2$, let $N=\min\{n\in\Bbb N\mid f_1(n)\neq f_2(n)\}$.

$|F(f_1)-F(f_2)|=\left |\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{f_1(n)}{3^{n+1}}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{f_2(n)}{3^{n+1}} \right |=\left |\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{f_1(n)-f_2(n)}{3^{n+1}} \right |= \left |\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\dfrac{f_1(n)-f_2(n)}{3^{n+1}} \right |= \left |\dfrac{f_1(N)-f_2(N)}{3^{n+1}}+\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\dfrac{f_1(n)-f_2(n)}{3^{n+1}} \right | \ge \left |\dfrac{f_1(N)-f_2(N)}{3^{N+1}}\right |- \left |\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\dfrac{f_1(n)-f_2(n)}{3^{n+1}} \right |=\dfrac{1}{3^{N+1}}- \left |\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\dfrac{f_1(n)-f_2(n)}{3^{n+1}} \right |\ge \dfrac{1}{3^{N+1}}- \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\left |\dfrac{f_1(n)-f_2(n)}{3^{n+1}} \right | \ge \dfrac{1}{3^{N+1}}- \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{3^{n+1}} =\dfrac{1}{3^{N+1}}- \dfrac{1}{2.3^{N+1}}=\dfrac{1}{2.3^{N+1}}>0.$

Hence $f_1\neq f_2\implies F(f_1)\neq F(f_2)$. Thus $F$ is injective.

Comment: This is correct, but it is a very convoluted way to show that a number can be written in base 3 in at most one way using digits 0 and 1.

Comment: In your bound of $F(f)$ for the series convergence, I think you mean $f(n) \leq 2$, not $1$.

Comment: @GuidoA. Since $2=\{0,1\},f(n)\le 1$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$. Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: @Akira if that's your definition of $2$, then you are correct and I take that back. Some people note $k^\mathbb{N}$ to mean functions $\mathbb{N} \to \{1, \dots, k\}$.

Comment: Thank you @GuidoA.! In set theory, some experts told me a convention in set theory that $n=\{0,\cdots,n-1\}$.

Comment: @Tobias, is there a shorter way to show it formally?

Comment: @Ennar This is a general thing about expansions in any base, but if you do want to prove it formally, then it is mainly a matter of noting that a tail of all $1$s gives something smaller than having a $1$ one place earlier.

Comment: @Tobias, I agree and we all know it. This is what Akira does, isn't it? The technique might be more polished, but it's essentially proving that tails don't matter, as you say.

Comment: @Ennar Yeah, in essence that is what is being done. It could just be done in a shorter way (which is understandable. The first time you write up a proof of something, it is almost always much longer than necessary).